# How to distinguish between an explicit click by a user and a click by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Social media platforms - Facebook, Twitter etc. provide buttons such as *Like*, *Follow* to allow users to click and perform the action.

For example, this is a Follow button on mashable.com - clicking *Follow* directly makes the user follow the Mashable account on Twitter without actually taking the user to Twitter.

[Twitter Follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8NJ.png)

Or this, which directly Likes the page on Facebook.

[Facebook Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLW3.png)

Why is it not possible for, say a spam website to run a script to click all the *Follow* buttons on it's website to make the incoming users *Follow* the accounts Twitter or *Like* certain posts on Facebook?

I understand that the JS differentiates between a user intended click and a click by script. But how does it do that?

Comment: Why don't you try `captcha` ? There are many scripts you will get on net. Google's recaptcha is one of the easiest solution.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? would be a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it not possible for, say a spam website to run a script to click all the Follow buttons on it's website

Because those social plugins are rendered inside iframes that load their content from Facebook’s domain - and that means, the spam website has no access to it via JavaScript, because of the *Same Origin Policy*.

(Click-jacking would be a different issue - and is also one Facebook and the other social networks take measures against.)

Answer (score 0):

Programatically performed click is done via `node.dispatchEvent(event)` where the `event` is an Event or CustomEvent object, plus you can pass custom config file like

```
node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click', {
    details: config // your config event
}));
```

So the check might be done at least in 2 ways:

1) checking constructor or the `event` object (rather error-prone)

2) check how detailed is the `config` object you pass inside it.

The Origin Policy is another way, which is probably what you're looking after in this case.